# Timezone conversion from MST to target timezone not working in Perl

Tags: perl, timezone

```
my $apptStartDateTime = "20210401100000"; 
my $formatter = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time_zone => "MST");
my $dt_obj = $formatter->parse_datetime($apptStartDateTime);
$dt_obj->strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), "\n"; #prints 20210401100000
# to convert to a different zone:
$dt_obj->set_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles");
$dt_obj->strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), "\n";#prints 20210401100000
```

The above does not convert from MST to America/Los_Angeles. Can someone please help? I am new to Perl. Also, would the above code take care of DST?

Comment: If you change the timzone in line 2 to a different one, like `Europe/London`, you will see the time change. I think it doesn't like `MST`. Look at https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/mst for DST. It seems like that timezone doesn't have it. Use one with a location instead.

Comment: Right now (and for the test date-time) there is no difference between MST and America/Los_Angeles.  If you try 1st January 2021 instead, you'll see they differ as LA would then have no DST.  Some locales that use MST observe daylight saving (try America/Denver) other don't (America/Phoenix).

Comment: @martinclayton...thank you so much for pointing that out. I totally missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use US Mountain Time, which is identified by `America/Denver`. But even if the date-time is in US Mountain Time, that won't always give you the right answer.

---

If you refer to this [list of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), you'll see that

- US Mountain Standard Time (`MST`) is UTC-7.
- US Pacific Time (`America/Los_Angeles`) is UTC-8 in the winter, and UTC-7 in the summer.

The correct conversion of

```
2021-04-01 10:00:00 -07:00 (MST)
```

is therefore

```
2021-04-01 10:00:00 -07:00 (America/Los_Angeles)
```

DateTime properly converted the date-time.

Maybe you meant to use US Mountain Time, which is identified by `America/Denver` (UTC-7 in winter, UTC-6 in summer). However, that introduces an ambiguity. For one hour every year, you'll get the wrong answer due to the overlap during the DST change.

For example,

```
2020-11-01 02:30:00 (America/Denver)
```

could refer to both

```
2020-11-01 02:30:00 -05:00 (America/Denver)    Before "fall back"
2020-11-01 02:30:00 -06:00 (America/Denver)    After "fall back"
```

Date-times should be transmitted in UTC or provide the offset from UTC of the date-time. For example, using the standard RFC3339 format, you could use any of

```
2020-11-01T02:30:00-05:00
2020-11-01T07:30:00+00:00
2020-11-01T07:30:00Z
```

for the former and any of

```
2020-11-01T02:30:00-06:00
2020-11-01T08:30:00+00:00
2020-11-01T08:30:00Z
```

for the latter. Then, you could keep using DateTime::Format::Strptime (with `%z`), or use DateTime::Format::RFC3339.

Comment: If this answers your question, checking the mark next to it is the customary way to thank.